# Spanner Row Deletion policy - Update row after expired timestamp

Tags: ttl, google-cloud-spanner

I was wondering what's the exact behaviour of Spanner Row Deletion policy when the row gets updated after its been marked for deletion. Will be background process, care to check that the timestamp has been updated and no more expired row or will it continue to delete it?
Is there an easy way to replicate this behavior in dev as I cannot force trigger the deletion process (takes anywhere until 72 hours)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [how it works section](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/ttl#how_does_ttl_work) in the doc, background process first checks for eligibility then does a batch delete. The 2 steps are independent. Say row_x is eligible and identified in Step 1. The delete step will figure out if/how to batch then check if row_x has changed since step 1 identified it earlier. If it has changed, the process will go back to step 1 and determine row_x is not eligible so nothing happens.